# Get designer to generate AddRange for simple List property of UserControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have created a new UserControl like so:

```
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl {
    List<Fruit> _fruits = new List<Fruit>();

    public List<Fruit> Fruits {
        get {
            return _fruits;
        }
        set {
            _fruits = value;
        }
    }

    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The `Fruit` class simply contains two get/set properties and nothing else:

```
public class Fruit {
    public bool Edible {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

When I drag an instance of MyControl from the Visual Studio toolbox on a Form and then proceed to add `Fruit` objects to the `Fruits` collection of MyControl using the Visual Studio designer, I expected the designer to generate new `Fruit` instances and automatically add them to the `Fruits` collection in the designer-generated code by generating a call to the collections `AddRange` or `Add` method.

However it does not generate any `AddRange` code to add them to `MyControl`'s `Fruits` collection and so I end up with "lingering" `Fruit` instances in the code-behind. I already tried adding the `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` attribute to the `Fruits` property, but that did nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to create a type converter for fruit class which uses instance descriptor to create an instance of fruit.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Really? I was just playing around with it some more and now it suddenly started to simply work...? The only attribute that I have added is [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] just as I had before..?

Comment: It depends to the expectation. If you expect creating the fruit in a single line of code in designer, `fruit = new Fruit(true, "Apple")` then you definitely need the type converter in addition to `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content`. Otherwise, fruit will be created this way: `fruit = new Fruit();`  `fruit.Edible = true;` `fruit.Name = "Apple";` in different lines.

Comment: See the difference of having and not having the type descriptor in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` is needed for `Fruits` to let the designer know to serialize its content. Also the `Fruits` property doesn't need a public setter:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        Fruits = new List<Fruit>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<Fruit> Fruits { get; private set; }
}
```

As a result the following code will be generated:

```
Sample.Fruit fruit1 = new Sample.Fruit();
Sample.Fruit fruit2 = new Sample.Fruit();
Sample.Fruit fruit3 = new Sample.Fruit();
this.myControl1 = new Sample.MyControl();
// 
// myControl1
// 
fruit1.Edible = true;
fruit1.Name = "Apple";
fruit2.Edible = true;
fruit2.Name = "Orange";
fruit3.Edible = true;
fruit3.Name = "Banana";
this.myControl1.Fruits.Add(fruit1);
this.myControl1.Fruits.Add(fruit2);
this.myControl1.Fruits.Add(fruit3);
```

**Cleaner designer generated code**

If you want to have a cleaner code generated, like following:

```
this.myControl1 = new Sample.MyControl();
// 
// myControl1
// 
this.myControl1.Fruits.Add(new Sample.Fruit(true, "Apple"));
this.myControl1.Fruits.Add(new Sample.Fruit(true, "Orange"));
this.myControl1.Fruits.Add(new Sample.Fruit(true, "Banana"));
```

You need to create a [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) for your `Fruit` class which uses [`InstanceDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) to create an instance of the class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;
[TypeConverter(typeof(FruitConverter))]
public class Fruit
{
    public Fruit() { }
    public Fruit(bool edible, string name) : this()
    {
        Edible = edible;
        Name = name;
    }
    public bool Edible { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class FruitConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) return true;
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
        CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) {
            var ci = typeof(Fruit).GetConstructor(new Type[] { 
                typeof(bool), typeof(string) });
            var t = (Fruit)value;
            return new InstanceDescriptor(ci, new object[] { t.Edible, t.Name });
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: Hello @Reza Aghaei your approach very awesome. thank you much my man :). Would you mind to tell me how to implement AddRange() not Add() method. As I try my best and fail. I try PropertyInfo[] and pass to InstanceDescriptor but I didn't success at all.  I need 2nd approach in screen image see please https://prnt.sc/13m8gjw   . Some few tips will be great :)