# A custom TypeConverter for generates AddRange() in WinForms designer not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, typeconverter

From question: [Get designer to generate AddRange for simple List property of UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580202/get-designer-to-generate-addrange-for-simple-list-property-of-usercontrol)

Following TypeConverter doesn't generate AddRange(). While I see Some Controls generate it with same code manner.

**Form1.designer.cs**

```
        // userControl11
        // 
        this.userControl11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Fruits.Add(new WindowsFormsApp2.Fruit(false, null));
        this.userControl11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 224);
        this.userControl11.Name = "userControl11";
```

**It should be**

`this.userControl1.Fruits.AddRange(new Fruite[]{new Fruit(X, Y), new Fruit(X, Y), etc})`

While I see standard controls do same but it generates well:

```
    // listBox1
    // 
    this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {   // WORKS in standard controls...
    "123",
    "123",
    "123"});
```

**My code:**

```
 [TypeConverter(typeof(FruitConverter))]
    public class Fruit
    {
        public Fruit() { }
        public Fruit(bool edible, string name) : this()
        {
            Edible = edible;
            Name = name;
        }
        public bool Edible { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FruitConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) return true;
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && (value is Fruit pi))
            {
                ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(Fruit).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(bool), typeof(string) });
                object[] pars = new object[] { pi.Edible, pi.Name };
                return new InstanceDescriptor(ctor, pars);
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

**Test in UserControl**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private Collection<Fruit> fruits = new Collection<Fruit>();
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public Collection<Fruit> Fruits => fruits;

}
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really too hard. But here's article explain some:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio

> Third, the collection class must implement one or both of the
> following methods: Add and AddRange. Although IList interface has an
> Add member and CollectionBase implements IList, you still have to
> implement an Add method for your collection, given that CollectionBase
> declares an explicit member implementation of the IList’s Add member.
> The designer serializes the collection according to what method you
> have implemented. If you have implemented both, the AddRange is
> preferred.

**When serializing with the Add method, for every item it uses a new line.**

```
this.tc.SimpleItems.Add(new Test.Items.SimpleItem_FullTc(-1, "Item1"));
this.tc.SimpleItems.Add(new Test.Items.SimpleItem_FullTc(-1, "Item2"));`
```

When the designer uses the AddRange method, all the items are added on a single line.

```
this.tc.SimpleItems.AddRange
  (new Test.Items.SimpleItem[]{new Test.Items.SimpleItem_FullTc(-1, "Item1"),
new Test.Items.SimpleItem_FullTc(-1, "Item2")});
```

**So you must implement a class inherits from `Collection<T>` or `CollectionBase` then add AddRange() Method.**